# Remove MSBuild.ILMerge.Task Dependency from DevOps Nuget Artifact Package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, devops, class-library

I am trying to remove the MSBuild.ILMerge.Task Dependency from a DevOps Nuget Artifact Package. Can't seem to find a way to just ignore this one dependency.

[image: DevOps Nuget Package Dependencies]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is using `PackageReference`, you should use [`<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets).

If your project is using `packages.config`, you should use [`developmentDependency="true"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config#schema)